# SQL SELECT Error

Tags: php

Whats wrong with this select statement? I'm getting this error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. I've tried everything but cannot figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
            $sql = "SELECT gm.gname, gp.logo
        FROM gmembers AS gm
        LEFT JOIN groups AS gp ON gp.name = gm.gname
        WHRER gm.mname ='$log_username'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$g_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Have a look at your sql spelling. You've written `WHRER` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: echo mysqli_error ( $db_conx );

Comment: This question is asked like 5 times each day.  Did you search or check the "Related" questions?  Anyway, the solution is to use *error checking*!  It's bad to just *assume* your query worked.  `if($query === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($db_conx)); }`

Comment: This means that the query is failing.  Print `mysqli_error` after the `mysqli_query` to see what's going on.  Likely, it's the typo in `WHRER` that's supposed to be `WHERE`.

Comment: And you're also open to SQL injection, you should fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
SELECT gm.gname, gp.logo
FROM gmembers AS gm
LEFT JOIN groups AS gp ON gp.name = gm.gname
WHERE gm.mname ='$log_username'
```

Try running this in the *phpmyadmin* / whichever GUI you are using for DB.